# About VBA Code returns multiple values

Tags: vba, excel

I need help here to understand how and from where the variable Ret has the value "2".

I am not able to understand this code, can someone help me please.

```
Function Test(ByVal Input1 As Integer, ByVal Input2 As Integer, _
    ByRef Output1 As Integer, ByRef Output2 As Integer) As Integer

      Output1 = Input1 + Input2
      Output2 = Input1 - Input2
      Test = Output1 + Output2

End Function

Sub Test2()

    Dim Ret As Integer, Input1 As Integer, Input2 As Integer, _
    Output1 As Integer, Output2 As Integer
    Input1 = 1
    Input2 = 2
    Ret = Test(Input1, Input2, Output1, Output2)
    Sheet1.Range("A1") = Ret     ' 2
    Sheet1.Range("A2") = Output1 ' 3
    Sheet1.Range("A3") = Output2 '-1

End Sub
```

Comment: Read this : http://www.cpearson.com/excel/byrefbyval.aspx

Comment: @cyboashu OP's question seems to be more about `Test = Output1 + Output2`, which assigns the function's return value, which is assigned to `Ret` at the call site. Basically, "function calls 101".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Return value**

Return values in VBA are done by setting the name of the function equal to a value. Example:

```
Function myFunction()
    myFunction = 123
End Function
```

When I call `myFunction`, I can assign the function's return value to a variable, e.g. like:

```
returnValue = myFunction
```

`returnValue` will now have the value 123

In your example, the function Test returns the result of `Output1 + Output2`:

```
Output1 + Output2 = 3 + (-1) = 2
```

Therefore, the function Test returns the value 2

**ByRef/ByVal Parameters**

The other thing that's going on here, are the two different types of parameters.

Passing a parameter **`ByVal`** (by value) creates a copy of the variable and passes that copy into the function. Therefore, if I adjust the variable inside the function, its value in the caller function doesn't change. Example:

```
Function MyFunction(ByVal num)
    num = 2
End Function
```

and then I call the function like so:

```
count = 1
Call MyFunction(count)
MsgBox count
```

The MsgBox will display the number 1. The variable `count` was copied to a different variable (`num` inside MyFunction) and when `num` was assigned the value 2, `count` remained unchanged.

Passing a parameter **`ByRef`** is the opposite: The parameter isn't copied, but passed directly (as a reference ~ as a "link") to the function.

Let's look at the above MyFunction again, but imagine changing the parameter to ByRef instead of ByVal. In that case, `MsgBox count` will display the value 2. When we pass `count` ByRef to MyFunction, `num` becomes an alias of the same variable as `count` and when `num` is assigned the value 2, `count` is the same variable, so it also now has the value 2.

Comment: Note that unlike (most?) other languages, in VB6/VBA the implicit default is `ByRef`, which means everything is passed by reference unless specified otherwise: unless you're purposely assigning to a parameter, you normally want them passed `ByVal`, by value.

Comment: Could you please give little more information about ByRef that how it works.

Answer (score 0):

`Ret` gets the value of the result of the `Test` Function

```
Ret = Test(Input1, Input2, Output1, Output2)
```